# Frontend and backend url not matching

Tags: reactjs, express, routes

I have a problem with matching routes. I am runnning react app on port localhost:3000, and node/express server is running on port localhost:3001.
I am trying to create a club by firing this request on the frontend:

```
async addClub(club) {
   try {
      let postData = await fetch(`${this.backendUrl}/club`, {
         method: 'POST',
         headers: {
           'Accept': 'application/json',
               'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({...club}),
      });
```

**this.backendUrl is correctly imported**

Route on the backend file is:

```
  router.post('/club', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const body = req.body;
    await new Club(body).save((err, club) => {
      if (err) return console.log(err)
      console.log('New club created');
      res.status(200).send({ msg: 'Club created' });
    });
  } catch(err) {
    res.status(400).json({
      msg: 'Bad Request'
    })
  }
})
```

But for some reason frontend execution cannot find route specified on the backend.

I get an error: **POST http://localhost:3001/club 404 (Not Found)**

I have other routes through which I create other things and they work perfectly.

Comment: do you have proxy in your package.json for your frontend ?

Comment: Udendu Abasili I do not. Never needed it. As I said other routes, and there are plenty of them, all CRUD operations, work just fine.

Comment: How do you mount the router in the application?